# How do I stop Outlook from opening other windows?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 365 Desktop App. Whenever I double click on something, eg an email, it opens in a new window. Is there any way to stop this ie keep Outlook as an SDI rather than MDI? I seem to remember this being an option in the olden days but cannot find it anymore.

Comment: One click, inline, two clicks, new window. No?

Comment: @Tetsujin that's how it has always been to me. I've never seen an option to block that either and I've used a lot of versions over the years.

Comment: @Mokubai - It just seems to me "that's how things work". Same in Explorer, or on a Mac… or anywhere. One click select, two clicks action. The only place that's not generally true would be the web.

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps OP may have previously been using the Outlook Web App version without realising it which is available via the accounts area in the settings.

Comment: One-click nothing happens.

Comment: Duh, so it was not showing the reading pane in view. Thanks for helping a dimwit! IE `View - reading pane - Right` (was set to Off)

Comment: Totally agree with Tetsujin, and it's convenient to turn on reading pane to review the message. By the way, it's also recommended to turn on to-do bar in view settings, so that we could review more items(such as tasks and calendar items) in Mail view.

Comment: Do you still have any questions about it? If not, it's recommended to post your solution to answer and mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments pointed me in the right direction: `View - Reading Pane - Right` (was set to Off). Once it is on, a single-click means I can see the email without a pop up.

Comment: Cool. It would be better if you could mark it to answer :).